# IBM Datapower SOMA and Suds: single parameter-less method and many types

Tags: python, suds, ibm-datapower

I'm trying to get Suds to work with IBM's SOMA operations for Datapower. However, Suds detects only 1 method, moreover a parameter-less one: `operation()`.

```
Service ( xml-mgmt ) tns="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management/wsdl"
    Prefixes (1)
       ns0 = "http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management"
    Ports (1):
       (xml-mgmt)
          Methods (1):
             operation()
          Types (1565):
             ns0:ActionAddKnownHost
             ns0:ActionAddPasswordMap
             ns0:ActionAddSelTestEntry
             ns0:ActionAddTrustedHost
             ns0:ActionApplyPatch
             ns0:ActionB2BArchiveNow
             ns0:ActionB2BHASwitchPrimary
             ns0:ActionBackupConfig
             ns0:ActionBootDelete
             ns0:ActionBootSwitch
             ... (hundreds and hundreds of more types)
```

Give this single parameter-less operation, only a XML skeleton is generated and posted to the endpoint.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <ns1:Body>
        <ns0:request/>
    </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is there a way, given Suds interpretation of the WSDL and XSD's, as reflected above, to "embed" additional information in this request based on the information provided by the numerous types? My alternative so far is to generate the XML myself and inject it into the endpoint, but that beats the purpose of using a high-level library like Suds.

Many thanks in advance